# How to move a div when a checkbox is checked in .html/.css

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am making a webpage with .css and .html and have a div "rowcontainer" which I would like to move inside the div "selected" when the checkbox is checked then preferably move back if it is unchecked. Also I am planning to have a lot of these rows so is there I way I can give them separate names so I can refer to them individually?

edit: I have found a solution, thanks to @mplungjan I have added the code which worked for me below.

```js
            <script type="text/javascript">
                const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
                const main =    document.getElementById("tablecontainer")
                main.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                const tgt = e.target;
                if (tgt.classList.contains("move")) {
                    const rowContainer = tgt.closest(".rowcontainer");
                    if (tgt.checked) selected.append(rowContainer)
                    else main.append(rowContainer)
                    }
                })
                selected.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                const tgt = e.target;
                if (tgt.classList.contains("move")) {
                    const rowContainer = tgt.closest(".rowcontainer");
                    main.append(rowContainer)
                    }
                })
            </script>
```

```css
.selected{
    margin:auto;
    width: 80%px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}

#tablecontainer {
    min-height:200px;
}

.rowcontainer {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 30px;
}

.name {
    line-height: 30px;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px
}

.ako {
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}

.select {
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id = "selected" class = "selected"></div>
<div id="tablecontainer">
                    <div class = "rowcontainer" style = "background-      color: #e6e6e6;">
                        <div class = "name"><t>Patrick Star</t></div>
                        <div class = "ako"><t>13GWZ</t></div>
                        <div class = "select">
                            <input type = "checkbox" class = "checkbox move">
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

No need to name them. but you will need JavaScript

If you need to keep the order, you will need to have a list of them and possibly use a data attribute

```js
const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
const main = document.getElementById("mainContainer")
main.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("move")) {
    const rowContainer = tgt.closest(".rowcontainer"); // the container the checkbox is in
    if (tgt.checked) selected.append(rowContainer)
    else main.append(rowContainer)
  }
})
```

```css
.selected {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.rowcontainer {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
}

.name {
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px
}

.ako {
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

.select {
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

.checkbox {
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div class="selected"></div>

  <div class="rowcontainer">
    <div class="name">
      <bt>Name</bt>
    </div>
    <div class="ako">
      <bt>Ako</bt>
    </div>
    <div class="select">
      <bt>Select</bt>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox move">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have added the javascript to my code and made the changes to my ccs/html. When I check the box nothing happens, the rowcontainer does not move but when I deselect it does append it to the end of main container. I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>" on this line "if (tgt.checked) selected.append(rowContainer)". Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Ok realized I had the javascript in the wrong place so I have fixed that and now the row is moving into selected when selected but it is not moving back when unselected. This time there are no error messages. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I have figured this out as well, I just needed to add another "eventListner". Thank you so much for your help this solution works perfectly. I will update the post with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script on your page.

```js
 const maindiv = document.querySelector('.selected'); // this is your maindiv 'selected'
        maindiv.style.backgroundColor = 'green';  // colored so that change is visible

        const row = document.querySelector('.rowcontainer'); // this is your row
        row.style.backgroundColor = 'cornflowerblue';   // colored so that change is visible

        const checkbox = document.querySelector('.checkbox');   // this is your checkbox

        window.onload = check;          // this checks if he checkbox is checked or not when page loads up
        checkbox.onclick = check;          // this will check when user click on chekbox

        // the function that does all the work
        function check() {
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                maindiv.appendChild(row);   // it will append your row to maindiv (if chekbox is checked)
            }else{
                document.body.appendChild(row); // it will append your row to the body (if checkbox is not checked)
            }
            
        }
```